# Map a function to every given key of a nested association

Tags: associations, hold

Consider for example the nested association:

```
myA = <|"d" -> <|"c" -> <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>|>|>
```

It is easy to map a function to a key on the first level:

```
MapAt["c" /. # &, myA, "d"]
```

[image]

but MapAt doesn't work with levels higher than 1

```
MapAt["a" /. # &, myA, "c"]
```

[image]

So I tried a workaround, trasforming all the associations to lists:

```
  Replace[
    myA /. Association -> ass
    ,
    Rule["c", x_] -> Rule["c", ("a" + "b") /. x], Infinity
  ] /. ass -> Association
```

getting the correct result, but with some errors that I can't fix

[image]

I've tried with Hold, but it looks like it works at level 1 only.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you need to extract a value or is this only an example of a function `"c" /. # &`? p.s. it would help to have desired results presented as it is not clear what is the ultimate goal.

Comment: `MapAt["a" /. # &, myA, {All, "c"}]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a function that finds all keys of a given name anywhere in your data structure and maps a function onto those positions:

```
mapAtKeyEveryWhere[assoc_, fun_, key_] := MapAt[
  fun,
  assoc,
  Append[Key[key]] /@ Position[
    assoc,
    KeyValuePattern[key -> _]
  ]
];
```

Test it:

```
myA = <|"d" -> <|"c" -> <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>|>|>;
mapAtKeyEveryWhere[myA, ("a" + "b") /. # &, "c"]
(* <|"d" -> <|"c" -> 3|>|> *)
```

Is that what you have in mind?

Comment: Perfect, thanks Sjoerd!